# For what values of $r$ does $y=e^{rx}$ satisfy $y'' + 5y' - 6y = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For what values of $r$ does $y=e^{rx}$ satisfy $y'' + 5y' - 6y = 0$?

#### Attempt:

$y' = [e^{rx}] (r)$

$y''= r^2e^{rx}$

Comment: Why'd you stop there? Plug them in!

Comment: The function $x\mapsto e^{rx}$ is a solution to the ODE $y''+5y'-6y=\bf 0$, if, and only if, $r^2+5r-6=0$.

Comment: and then you find $r_1=1, r_2=-6$ and $y(x)=Ae^{x}+Be^{-6x}$.

Comment: @GitGud when you plugged it in, why did the e^rx just dissapear?

Comment: @GitGud oh wait nvm it gets factored out and can never equal zero, makes sense thank you all!

Comment: @Jessica : I'm assuming this is for a class, and I HOPE you have a textbook.  Your $r$ must solve the _characteristic equation_ associated with the differential equation.  People discovered this centuries (?) ago, you can read all about it in any ODE book, there should be examples just like this, and you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plug them in, you obtain : $$r^2+5r-6=0$$
Solving this equation you get $r=1$ or $r=-6$.

That means that the general solution of the suggested ODE is : $$y(x)=ae^t + be^{-6t}, (a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$$