# What do 'general solution' and ODE mean?

Tags: calculus

In an answer to this question, For what values of $r$ does $y=e^{rx}$ satisfy $y'' + 5y' - 6y = 0$?, URL (version: 2013-11-13): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566059

$y' = [e^{rx}] (r)$

$y''= r^2e^{rx}$

It says:

**If you plug them in, you obtain : $$r^2+5r-6=0$$
Solving this equation you get $r=1$ or $r=-6$.
That means that the general solution of the suggested ODE is : $$y(x)=ae^t + be^{-6t}, (a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$$**

What do 'general solution' and ODE mean? Where does the last equation come from and what is its significance?

Comment: ODE = ordinary differential equation, I'm not sure what they mean by 'general solution', but I think they are just referring to the fact that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary constants -- someone correct me if I'm wrong though. Also just as a heads-up, PDE=partial differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

A differential equation is an equation involving derivatives. An ODE or ordinary differential equation is a differential equation that contains one independent variable and its derivatives. $y'$ refers to the derivative of $y=f(x)$, $y''$ refers to the second derivative  of $y=f(x)$, etc.

The general solution is the family of functions that satisfy the differential equation.

One thing we can do to find a solution is guess that a solution to the differential equation is of the form $y=e^{rx}$ and check to make sure that there does exist some $r$ such that the ODE will be satisfied:

$$y''+5y'-6y=0$$

Substituting in $y''$, $y'$, and $y$ gives:

$$r^2e^{rx}+5re^{rx}-6e^{rx}=0$$

Dividing by $e^{rx}$ on both sides gives an equation which is often called the characteristic equation:

$$r^2+5r-6=0$$

So $r=-6$ or $r=1$. We may check to make sure that $y=e^{-6x}$ and $y=e^{1x}$ are both solutions if we like.

An equation of the form:

$$c_1y''+c_2y'+c_3y=0$$

Is called a $2nd$ order homogenous differential equation. It is simple to check that if $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are both solutions to this differential equation then so is:

$$c_1g(x)+c_2h(x)$$

This accounts for a more general solution to the differential equation of interest. However proving this is the unique general solution if we want our solution to be continuous takes a bit more work. However, let me note that for a differential equation like a 2nd order home genius differential  equation there is a catch when the roots to the  characteristic equation are repeated. See this [Repeated Roots](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/RepeatedRoots.aspx)

Or this video [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/second-order-differential-equations/complex-roots-characteristic-equation/v/repeated-roots-of-the-characteristic-equation)

By the way his previous differential equation videos I find pretty intuitive, it might be worth it to check them out.

Comment: I'm supposed to avoid saying 'thanks' in this text box, so I will say 'I'm grateful' for your valuable answer and links to extra resources.